# Removing Gmail account from Gmail app, but keeping it in Google Inbox app

Tags: gmail

On my Android I run the Google Inbox app as my personal email client. I run the Gmail app for my company mail. Problem for me is that since I have my personal Gmail account synced with my phone it will automatically show up in Gmail, causing double notifications to show up for each new email I receive, one from Gmail and one from Inbox.

How do I remove my Google account from Gmail, and only keep it in Inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't configure an account only for inbox, or only for gmail.

But you can disable gmail notifications for your personnal account.
In gmail, top-left menu, settings, "your-personnal-account", uncheck "notifications".

Comment: Hi Egoz, thanks for your answer! I just tried it out, and removing the notification for my personal email on the Gmail app does practically what I needed. Now the multiple notifications won't bug me any more. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can also go into settings - > accounts -> google, then disable sync for inbox and gmail on the respective accounts, for one step further.